# SQL server 2008 - subquery returned more than one value

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

SQL server 2008 - An error occurred while reading data from the query result set. Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

```
This came up as soon I added the case statement with CHDOCS. Everything else worked
 fine until that point. Can anyone help me out with this one please?


SELECT
CHDOCS.MAILING_ID
,CASE WHEN (SELECT CHDOCS.MAILING_DOCUMENT
       FROM CHDOCS 
       WHERE
               CHDOCS.MAILING_DOCUMENT LIKE N'%EX%')IS NOT NULL

               THEN (SELECT CHDOCS.MAILING_DOCUMENT
       FROM CHDOCS 
       WHERE
               CHDOCS.MAILING_DOCUMENT LIKE N'%EX%') ELSE '' END AS 'DOC'

     FROM CHDOCS
```

Comment: Obviously there is more than one row with a document that matches that pattern. Which one should SQL return?

Comment: I would like to return all of them if that is possible. Is there another way to write this?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: If there is more than one row of CHDOCS.MAILING_DOCUMENT.. I just want another row of CHDOCS.MAILING_ID

Comment: So why not just `SELECT Mailing_ID, Mailing_Document FROM dbo.CHDOCS WHERE Mailing_Document LIKE N'%EX%';`? Or `SELECT Mailing_ID, Mailing_Document = CASE WHEN Mailing_Document LIKE N'%EX%' THEN Mailing_Document ELSE N'DOC' END FROM dbo.CHDOCS;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use a `CASE` statement against a result set - it must be run against a single value.

I believe this is what you are trying to accomplish, which is an evaluation on each `MAILING_DOCUMENT` field in the `CHDOCS` table:

```
SELECT CHDOCS.MAILING_ID

    -- Check if the Mailing Document field matches the pattern *EX*
    ,CASE WHEN CHDOCS.MAILING_DOCUMENT LIKE N'%EX%' 
        THEN CHDOCS.MAILING_DOCUMENT  -- It does, return the field value.
        ELSE ''                       -- It doesn't, return empty.
        END AS DOC

FROM CHDOCS
```

Comment: This works! Thank you! I just started out learning sql. Appreciate the help

Answer (score 0):

Your this query

```
SELECT
    CHDOCS.MAILING_ID, ISNULL(CHDOCS.MAILING_DOCUMENT,'')
    FROM CHDOCS
WHERE CHDOCS.MAILING_DOCUMENT LIKE N'%EX%'
```